# How can I convert a nested EJS foreach loop to HBS foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, ejs, viewengine

I was using EJS on my project but I had to change it to HBS for a reason. So I'm trying to translate my ejs code to hbs. However, the syntax of hbs really confuses me.
This is my ejs code: (Sorry, the variables are not English. I hope you understand my code.)

```
 <% projeler.forEach(proje_dizisi=> { %>


<% proje_dizisi.forEach(proje=> { %>


  <div id="reg-modal<%= proje.id %>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content d-flex">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <h5 class="modal-title w-100 display-1">
            <%= proje.proje_ismi %>
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


          <div class="project_details_wrapper">

            <h4 class="text-center fs-3 mb-4">Proje Detayları</h4>

            <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
              <tbody>

                <tr>
                  <th>İsim</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.isim %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Soy İsim</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.soyisim %>
                  </td>

                <tr>
                  <th>Şirket</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.sirket %>
                  </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <th>Departman</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.departman %>
                  </td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                  <th>Kategori</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.proje_kategorisi%>
                  </td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                  <th>Proje Açıklaması</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.proje_aciklamasi %>
                  </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                  <th>Proje Eklenme Tarihi</th>
                  <td>
                    <%= proje.proje_eklenme_tarihi %>
                  </td>
                </tr>


              </tbody>
            </table>

            <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/randomForLibrary/<%= proje.proje_resmi_url %>">

            <p class="mt-3">

              <%= proje.proje_aciklaması%>


            </p>

            <div class="mt-5">

              <h3>Proje Dosyaları</h3>


              <a href="./user_files/<%= proje.proje_dosyalari_url %>" download>

                Projeye ait dosyaları indirin
                <!-- <input type="button" class="btn--green" value="Download"> -->
              </a>

            </div>


          </div>
```

I need the version of HBS of my code. I can't convert it using #each syntax. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `.forEach` loops that wrap your template are suspicious to me and force me to assume that `projeler` is an array of arrays. With this assumption, there isn't much more that is required to convert your template to  Handlebars than replacing the `.forEach` loops with `#each` loops and, of course, changing the ejs tags to mustaches `{{ }}`.

Your converted template would look something like:

```
{{#each projeler as |proje_dizisi|}}
  {{#each proje_dizisi as |proje|}}
    <div id="reg-modal{{proje.id}}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content d-flex">
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h5 class="modal-title w-100 display-1">{{proje.proje_ismi}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="project_details_wrapper">
              <h4 class="text-center fs-3 mb-4">Proje Detayları</h4>
              <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>İsim</th>
                      <td>{{proje.isim}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Soy İsim</th>
                      <td>{{proje.soyisim}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Şirket</th>
                      <td>{{proje.sirket}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Departman</th>
                      <td>{{proje.departman}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Kategori</th>
                      <td>{{proje.proje_kategorisi}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Proje Açıklaması</th>
                      <td>{{proje.proje_aciklamasi}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Proje Eklenme Tarihi</th>
                      <td>{{proje.proje_eklenme_tarihi}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/randomForLibrary/<%= proje.proje_resmi_url %>">
              <p class="mt-3">{{proje.proje_aciklaması}}</p>
              <div class="mt-5">
                <h3>Proje Dosyaları</h3>
                <a href="./user_files/{{proje.proje_dosyalari_url}}" download>
                  Projeye ait dosyaları indirin
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/rjpg9vkm/) for reference.